# How to root Tecno WX3P?

Tags: rooting

I have Tecno WX3P phone. I would like to change the font of my phone but it just won't do so. I'm told that for me to be able to change its font I should root it. But I don't know how to root my phone.

How to root Tecno WX3P?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device). xda is more appropriate place for rooting guides.

Answer (score 0):

The following description is rather generic. It should just give you the right key words to use a search engine to find the matching information. This link using the MediaTek specific SP flash tool looks promising: [wx3](https://www.androidvillaz.net/how-to-root-tecno-wx3-install-twrp-recovery/) (The SP tool is a MediaTek world specific way to flash images to a phone)

## Classical approach

- Install the Android SDK or something where the `adb` cmd line tool is included
- Go to the settings -> About / Info -> Search for "Build number" (maybe buried in sub menus like software information)

  - Tap it 7 times to enable the developer options
- Go to the settings -> Developer options
- Enable developer mode

  - Enable USB debugging
  - Enable OEM unlocking
- Boot into fastboot `adb reboot fastboot`
- Unlock phone `fastboot oem unlock ...` (Here there might be some other steps necessary like entering some special code e.g. some kind of `fastbooet oem <oem specific command>` -> entering it to the OEM web page -> `fastboot flash <some binary>`)
- Install a custom recovery like TWRP (there are different versions for each device, for you problem this one might work: [TWRP X3](https://dl.twrp.me/x3/))

  - Note that TWRP does not currently work with Android 10 (status Dec. 2019). The way partitions are working and the mounting of `/system` has changed.
- Download SuperSU (not all version are working, also newer releases ) and install SuperSU to get su (and so root access) from within TWRP

## Newer Approach

- Do the same like above and stop before installing TWRP. Maybe you do not need to install it, but just run it once with `fastboot boot twrp <device specific name>.img` to use it for installing the Magisk zip.
- Use [Magisk](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html)

  - Get the zip from [downloads](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases)
  - There are easy ways like directly booting this with `fastboot`, sometimes a "build image patching" is required (e.g. under Android 10)